# How can I make a sphere follow an eight-like path in Python using OpenGL?

Tags: python, matrix, opengl, rotation

I have to make a sphere move in the shape of the infinite symbol for my computer graphics class.

I think I have managed to recreate the exact movement of the sphere in the following Python program as the task's diagram suggests.

These are the results:

[The sphere following a path in the shape of the number eight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPrR5.gif)

Here's my problem:

My program needs to do certain things in order to accomplish this:

1. I have to draw two models of the sphere. One is located at **(-8,4,0)** and the other is located at **(7,-3,0)**. I do this in order to place the spheres around two coordinates that are different from the origin.
2. I make the first model rotate around the coordinate **(-8,4,0)** until it does a half-loop. After that, I change it to the second model whose origin is at **(7,-3,0)** and it rotates all the way until it does a whole loop. Once it happens, I change it again to the first model and does a whole loop and a half. It repeats again, thus following the trajectory of an infinite symbol.

This what I have done in my python program

```
run = True
angle = 0
x_position = -8
y_position = 4
points_matrix = generate_sphere_points(x0=x_position, y0=y_position, z0=0)
points_matrix2 = generate_sphere_points(x0=-x_position-1, y0=-y_position+1, z0=0)
index = False
matrices_points = [points_matrix, points_matrix2]
delta_angle = -4
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    draw_world_axes()
    glLineWidth(1)
    glTranslatef(x_position, y_position, 0)
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1)
    plot_parametric_mesh(matrices_points[index])
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(10)

    if angle <= -180 or angle >= 180:
        index = not index
        x_position = -x_position - 1
        y_position = -y_position + 1
        delta_angle *= -1

    angle += delta_angle

pygame.quit()
```

While it works, I think you only need one sphere model. However,I haven't figured out how to make a sphere or even an object rotate around a coordinate different than the origin (0,0,0) without displacing that object as I create it. I know you can use `glRotatef()*glTranslatef()` to make an object rotate around the origin, but what I want is that it rotates around a coordinate I specify.

In this case, make one sphere model that rotates around one coordinate, then switches its center to a different coordinate, and repeat throughout the entire 8-loop.

Does anybody have an idea of how I could go about making a sphere rotate around a coordinate just using transformation matrices (translatef and rotatef) without having to change the sphere's center in its parametric equation and using only one model of the sphere to do the 8 loop instead of swapping the two models?

Comment: Rotate an object around an arbitrary (pivot) point: `glTranslate(origin); glTranslate(pivot); glRotate(angle); glTranslate(-pivot);`. Where `origin` is the point of origin (e.g. 0,0,0) and `pivot` the point (center) of rotation (e.g. 0,0,0, rotation around the objects own axis).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! @ErdalKüçük. I applied your advice in my code and it seems to be now working without the use of more than one model. I have a question regarding the `glTranslate(origin);`. I noticed it places the object on that point as its starting rotation position. However, I'm not sure if that's the purpose of that line of code, but I have tested it out and that appears to be outcome. Anyway, I'm quite grateful for your help.

Comment: Actually I get it now, my question is really regarding the order of matrix multiplication. I understand it first translates the objet to negative pivot coordinate, then rotates the object, then translates it back to pivot coordinate, and then translates it to origin point.  I just don't see how having the rotation between the two translations make the object spin around a fixed point. Is there a book I could check to learn more about this?

Comment: Yes, in OpenGL the order (of multiplication) is reversed. In this case, translate to the pivot point, rotate the object around that point, translate back to the object origin and then translate to the point where the object should appear. What would come next would be the view and lastly the projection transformations. In code, the order is reversed (projection -> view -> model transformations -> object vertices). I would recommend to have a look at: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems and/or https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [Lissajous curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve). This can be created by applying a transformation with different angles to the two axes. If both angles are the same, you get a circle. If one angle is twice as big as the other, you get an 8:

[image]

```py
import pygame
from OpenGL.GL import *
import math

pygame.init()
display = (400, 400)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display, pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
angle1 = 0
angle2 = 0
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    x = math.cos(angle1) * 0.8
    y = math.sin(angle2) * 0.4
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0)
    angle1 += 0.01
    angle2 += 0.02
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(-0.1, -0.1)
    glVertex2f(0.1, -0.1)
    glVertex2f(0.1, 0.1)
    glVertex2f(-0.1, 0.1)
    glEnd()

    clock.tick(100)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```